# Does Windows 2008 R2 Server Core support AppFabric Cache Clusters?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-core

I'm developing a solution that relies on Windows Server AppFabric's distributed cache features. Our current deployment scenario is to deploy use the same hosts for the cache cluster that our web apps and services run on.

This has lead to a few issues regarding memory availability (causing the cluster to throttle).

I can always throw more memory at the servers, but looking at memcached and other distributed cache cluster deployments, it seems the preferred strategy is to have dedicated cache hosts with limited server footprint, so that the memory can be gobbled up by the cache.

Server Core immediately jumps to mind, but I can't find any documentation supporting this strategy.  There's a lot of "limited Managed Code support" in the documentation and it doesn't look hopeful.

Comment: I'm interested to see if this has changed due to the fact .NET 4 is now supported on Windows Server 2008 R2 Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, at this time, Server 2008 R2 does not support .NET 4.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxsetup/thread/0cb922d1-b85e-43ba-b8ac-26400491480f

Since AppFabric has a dependency on .NET 4, this would stand to reason that it won't work.

Comment: psssst...linux. wouldn't it be interesting if someone got appfab cache running on linux before server core supported it? Speaking of which, what if you threw some linux instances out there running a stable build of memcache (or redis, or cassandra, or x)?  What does the application really care if you can find .net bindings for one of them? :P

Comment: After the debacle this afternoon just to deploy...I'm sorely tempted.

Comment: Core now supports .NET 4 http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22833